# How can i find a place or building name instead of address in android using GPS?

Tags: android, gps, android-location, android-gps

I want the actual place or building name instead of the address in andoird app using GPS.

For eg: If i'm in a shopping mall, My app should show that i'm in a XXXX mall.

Currently i am getting the address using latitude and longitude.

If followed this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

By using the [Google Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) you will be able to achieve what you seek. It returns an [`Address`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) object containing all the information about the location in `latitude` and `longitude` you passed to it. An example of how it can be used can be found below:

```
    if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context);
        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        // do stuff with addresses
    }
```

If it fails to return you a good `Address` object you can still try with the url method:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + String.valueOf(latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(longitude) + "&sensor=false&language=" + Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    JSONObject responseData;
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A");
        try {
            String text = s.next();
            responseData = new JSONObject(text);
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }

    // Do stuff with responseData, all the usefull informations are in this payload
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thanks